# Making legend items start in new column in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: legend, arcgis-pro

In ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1, I have just looked for the ability to start legend items in a new column.

This functionality is present in ArcMap's Legend Properties on the Items tab which appears below:

[image]

Has anyone found the equivalent functionality in ArcGIS Pro, or know when it may be expected to appear?

It is not mentioned in the [Work with a legend](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/work-with-a-legend.htm) documentation.

Nor does it appear on the `Element: Legend Item` pane (see below)

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.3.0, youu can select 'Legend Arrangement Options':

[image: Legend Arrangement Options]

Select 'Adjust Frame'.:

[image: Adjust Frame]

Then select the item from the legend that will go in a new column and return to the 'Element' settings, where a new option 'New Column' will have appeared.  This functions like the 'Place item(s) in new column' setting in ArcMap:

[image: New Column]

Comment: When you change the setting to "Adjust Frame" thought, it changed the size of my legend. I'm unable to maintain the size of my legend while just putting one feature in a new column. Seems like the functionality is close but not quite as good as ArcMap.

Comment: Functionality appears to be gone in 3.0.0. I can't get "New Column" to appear in my Legend Item options under any Fitting Strategy. I guess I'll be building multiple legends...

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in ArcGIS Pro 1.4 and I believe this is available even in 1.3.1.

1. Create a new legend.
2. Open the `Formal Legend` panel.
3. Click the `Legend Arrangement Options` button.

[image]

4. For `Fitting Strategy`, choose `Adjust columns and font size`. You can also specify the gap between columns under the `Spacing` section.

[image]

Note: if you choose `Adjust Columns` as your `Fitting Strategy`, then your legend will always have a new column for each item. However, I haven't found a property to specify the number of columns for the legend. You could work around this by resizing the legend item to force it to have a certain number of columns.

[image]

Your legend would look like this with the `Adjust columns and font size` strategy:

[image]

Your legend would look like this with the `Adjust columns` strategy:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS Pro 2.9, on the Format Legend/Legend Arrangement panel, select Manual Columns as the Fitting Strategy. Increase the number of columns if needed.

On the Contents/Drawing Order pane, the Column numbers appear with their layers indented. Drag and drop layers to move them to the top of a column.